# Android Intent information passing

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new to Android and have been looking around for an answer but can't seem to resolve my problem.  I have an intent that is passing information from one activity to another.  The activity receiving will display it when setContentView() is set to TextView.  If I try to use my xml file with setContentView() it will not display the String.

The Intent

```
public void clockin (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Mainmenu.class);
    String timedate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance90.getTime()0;
    intent.putExtra("TIME_DATE", timedate);
    startActivity(intent);
```

The Activity

```
public class Mainmenu extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
        String timedate = extras.getString("TIME_DATE");

        TextView textView = new TextView (this);
        text.View.setTextSize(20);
        text.View.setText(timedate);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);}}
```

The xml

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/TIME_DATE"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     />
```

Comment: The name of the extra is case sensitive.

Comment: What do you mean by "if setContentView() is TextView but not if I use my xml file."? Show how you are trying to do it that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MainMenu should be

```
 public class Mainmenu extends Activity{
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);  
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
    String timedate = extras.getString("Time_Date");// key must match
    TextView textView = new TextView (this); // initialize textview
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setText(timedate);
    setContentView(textView);   // set textview as layout content 
    }
    }

              or
```

activity_mainmenu.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainMenu

```
     public class Mainmenu extends Activity{
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);  
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
    String timedate = extras.getString("Time_Date");
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(timedate); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know you could call a layout id from inside a TextView.  Huge Help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Android idiom for naming extras that would prevent your problem:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Mainmenu.class);
   intent.putExtra(Mainmenu.EXTRA_DATE, timedate)
```

Activity:

```
    public class Mainmenu extends Activity {

      public final static String EXTRA_DATE="TIME_DATE":      

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

          ....              

          String timedate = extras.getString(EXTRA_DATE);
```

Comment: I apologize for the inconsistencies in my labels.  I'm inputting code from a different machine.  I did have the correct labels for the variables in my original code.  Just a little quick in getting the question up.  I can see how it would fix other errors that could crop up but it seems unnecessary for what I'm doing.  I do appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the extra is case sensitive, viz:

```
String timedate = extras.getString("Time_Date");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity, try this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String timedate = intent.getStringExtra("Time_Date");
```